hello world flask app on apache in a subdomain - getting python import errors on page access
I have a domain and subdomain registered and when accessing them, they go to the correct IP address and host.  The main domain is working fine, but its a static group of pages (pretty hard to mess that up, although God knows I have tried!)
The subdomain is supposed to be the flask app and that is where I am having issues.
I have the following apache/sites-available/propman.domain.com.conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    LogLevel debug
    ServerName propman.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.propman.domain.com
    ServerAlias localhost
    ServerAdmin user@domain.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias /propman /var/www/propman/test1.wsgi

    # DocumentRoot /var/www/propman
    <Directory /var/www/propman>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /propman/static /var/www/propman/web/static
    <Directory /var/www/propman/web/static>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/propman_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/propman_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

for completeness, here is my other domain that just serves static pages:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    ServerAlias localhost

    WSGIDaemonProcess domain_proc processes=1 threads=1 python-home=/var/www/domain
    WSGIProcessGroup domain_proc

    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
    <Directory /var/www/domain>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain_access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =10.13.0.107 [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

and /var/www/propman/test1.wsgi:
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/propman/')
activate_this = '/var/www/propman/.venv/bin/activate_this.py'

with open(activate_this) as file:
    exec(file.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

from test1 import application

and /var/www/propman/test1.py:
from flask import Flask

application = Flask(__name__)


@application.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello world!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, debug=True)

my Pipfile:
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
flask = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3"

I have run
cd /var/www/propman
sudo mkdir .venv
pipenv install

find . -type d ! -path "./.git/*" ! -path "./.venv/*" -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f ! -path "./.git/*" ! -path "./.venv/*" -exec chmod 644 {} \;

sudo apachectl --configtest (returns no errors)
sudo a2ensite propman.domain.com
sudo service apache2 restart

To test the venv:
pipenv shell
python test1.py
 * Serving Flask app 'test1'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080
* Running on http://10.13.0.107:8080
Press CTRL+C to quit
* Restarting with stat
* Debugger is active!
* Debugger PIN: 512-139-047

When I access http://10.13.0.107:8080 or http://10.13.0.107/propman:8080 I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
Once apache is up and running, when I access http://propman.domain.com, I get this in my access log when I access propman.domain.com/propman:
10.13.0.1 - - [08/Jun/2024:04:48:11 -0400] "-" 408 323 "-" "-"
10.13.0.1 - - [08/Jun/2024:04:48:12 -0400] "GET /propman HTTP/1.1" 404 844 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
10.13.0.1 - - [08/Jun/2024:04:48:12 -0400] "GET /propman HTTP/1.1" 404 520 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

when I access propman.domain.com:
10.13.0.1 - - [08/Jun/2024:04:50:24 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 844 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

I'm growing bald over this :-/

Use just import test1. It automatically looks for python files. If this doesn't work, separate the files by what folder they are in and try again.

thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't do anything.  After I updated the file, I ran pipenv update (do I need to do this?) thinking the test1.py needed to be compiled.  I noodled around the .venv folder and saw there was nothing in src (is there supposed to be?)  Normal venv's don't have src folders, so I really don't know

I added /var/www/propman/background.jpg.  When I navigate to https://propman.domain.com/background.jpg I see the image (yay).  But in my actual app, my static folder images is in /var/www/propman/web/static/images.  In my conf file I have this:     Alias /propman/static /var/www/propman/web/static (I tried Alias /static /var/www/propman/web/static as well)
<Directory /var/www/propman/web/static/>
    Allow from all
</Directory> but when I navigate to https://propman.domain.com/static/images/background.jpg or https://propman.domain.com/images/background.jpg I get FILE_NOT_FOUND


I have not seen any errors in the log file lately, so I put my test1.py back the way it was originally and restarted apache.  Still no errors.  I would have thought that it would generate an error each access?

When I intentionaly break code and restart apache, the error log doesn't seem to update?!?

I changed test1.wsg: from test1 import application and test1.py:application; @application.route("/propman");  and my propman.conf     LogLevel info.  Now I actually get positive updates in my error log with one exception:File does not exist: /var/www/html/  The only reference I can find to this in 000-default.conf and default-ssl.conf (should I delete these files?)

Is this normal for apache restart (date/times removed, but all occured in the same second): mod_wsgi (pid=420498): Shutdown requested 'flaskapp'.
mod_wsgi (pid=420498): Stopping process 'flaskapp'.
mod_wsgi (pid=420498): Destroying interpreters.
mod_wsgi (pid=420498): Cleanup interpreter ''.
mod_wsgi (pid=420498): Terminating Python.
mod_wsgi (pid=420498): Python has shutdown.
mod_wsgi (pid=420498): Exiting process 'flaskapp'.
mod_wsgi (pid=423061): Attach interpreter ''.

I have my server set up (I think) so that domain.com goes to /var/www/domain and propman.domain.com goes to /var/www/propman... navigating to either one seems to work (with the excptions noted) but is this causeing my issues?

I have updated the original post with my current installation.  It is not generating any errors in the logs, but it still does not work.  Any help would be most appreciated!

I put background.jpb in /var/www/propman and I am able to access propman.domain.com/background.jpg.  It  is supposed to reside in /var/www/prompan/web/static/images/background.jpg but I am unable to access it by propman.domain.com/static/images/background.jpg or propman.domain.com/images/background.jpg and I thougth that     Alias /propman/static /var/www/propman/web/static would have allowed this
